# Estou querendo exibir a quantidade de número negativos digitados usando funções

Tags: c++, funções

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int getnegativo(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int cont, cot=0;

    do {
        cout << "digite um valor: ";
        cin >> cont;

      cot = getnegativo(cont, cot);

    }while (cont != -1);

    cout << "número de valores negativos digitados: " << cot;

    cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}


int getnegativo(int a, int b){
if (a<0)
    b++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou te ajudar no caminho que está indo, mas tem várias coisas que seria melhor fazer de outra forma. Uma das mudanças é que eu provavelmente passaria o argumento por referência ao invés de fazer uma `return`, mas provavelmente ainda não aprendeu usar isto, então vai do jeito mais simples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int getnegativo(int a, int b){
    if (a < 0)  b++;
    return b;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int cont, cot = 0;
    do {
        cout << "digite um valor: ";
        cin >> cont;
      cot = getnegativo(cont, cot);

    } while (cont != -1);
    cout << "número de valores negativos digitados: " << cot;
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JENaJM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uhqosako-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Counter.cpp).

Eu começaria pensar no que está usando. Pra que usar `locale` em toda aplicação, se ela não tem função alguma no código? Ainda é pior por ser algo do C e não nativo do C++.